# Problema no replace usando for

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quero fazer uma sentença dançante a partir de uma frase dada pelo usuário, mas pela forma q eu fiz a saída está dando diferente e eu não consigo entender

```
    frase: str = input("Digite a sentença que deseja transformar: ")
frase: str = frase.lower()

cont: int = len(frase)

for x in range(cont):
    if x % 2 == 0:
        frase = frase.replace(frase[x], frase[x].upper())


print(frase)
```

Por algum motivo resultou em:

Digite a sentença que deseja transformar: Alo galera
Saída: ALO GALeRA

Comment: Não sei se entendi o que é pra fazer, mas enfim, segue meu chute: `frase = ''.join(c.upper() if i % 2 == 0 else c for i, c in enumerate(frase))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O replace vai substituir todas as ocorrências desse caratér na frase. Para substituir pelo índice tem que ser da seguinte forma:

```
for x in range(cont):
    if x % 2 == 0:
        frase = frase[:x] + frase[x].upper() + frase[x + 1:]
```